# What is the maximum length of a custom url protocol using synchronous pluggable protocols in internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, url, browser, uri

I'm running into a hard limit in Internet Explorer with application protocol's that exceed 508 characters in length. This limit is not enforced in other browsers, chrome etc...

The documentation on MSDN([1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) does not seem to mention the maximum permissible length in the scheme-specific portion of the URI or total length including scheme.

508 characters is well below general limits for urls in IE reported to be 2083 characters ([2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427)).

Does anyone know if this is expected behavior, i'm using IE8, or perhaps I've got something wrong here?

References:

- [Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Maximum URL length is 2,083 characters in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427)

Answer (score 6):

I recently ran into this same problem and come up with the following solution.  If you try to assign the URL directly like this:

```
 document.location.href = theUrlWithTheCustomProtocol;
```

you will run into this 508 character limit error and in IE8 you'll get a JavaScript error saying something about The "data area passed to a system call is too small."

To get around this problem, I switched from the above code to using JQuery to create an hidden iframe like this:

```
// Remove old frame
$('#hiddenIFrame').remove();

// Add new one
$('<iframe />', {
    'id': 'hiddenIFrame',
    'name': 'hiddenIFrame',
    'src': theUrlWithTheCustomProtocol,
    'style': 'display: none;'
}).appendTo("body");
```

This gets around the IE 508 character limit using document.location.href and this solution works for IE, FireFox, Chrome, and Safari.

Comment: In my tests, this increases the limit to 2,046 characters in IE 9–11. (Curiously, it's 2,047 characters in IE 8.) It's only a 4x increase, but it can be just enough in some situations. Great find.

Comment: Looks like 2040ish characters now works with `window.location.href`in Chromium browsers at least.

For me this is on Windows - wonder if any different on other platforms?

Answer (score 3):

```
508 + some bookkeeping = 512 bytes
```

I think that the browser, after splitting off the protocol, stores it in a temporary buffer of a fixed size. Why, I don't know, and this seems like behaviour that might change in the future. Don't bank on it.

I'm also wondering why you'd need a protocol this long. Even a `GUID` is only 36 characters when expressed as hex digits plus dashes.