# "Error: The data area passed to a system call is too small" when redirecting inside an iFrame - IE & Edge - Angular 8

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm working on a Angular 8 project and I'm trying to do a redirection to a long url (almost 3000 characters long) inside an iFrame, and Edge is raising the error.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The data area passed to a system call is too small. Error: The data area passed to a system call is too small. at prototype.pushState (https://www.mockurl.com/account/vendor-es2015.abdc12341bcd1234abcd.js:1:716248) at d.prototype.pushState (...
```

Both the parent and the child are in the same domain.

I found that Edge and IE have some limitations about the length of their urls, but I haven't been able to find a fix for my issue.

Ref:

[What is the maximum length of a custom url protocol using synchronous pluggable protocols in internet explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017734/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-custom-url-protocol-using-synchronous-pluggable)

Comment: Can you `POST` to the URL instead? As you've noted the 3000 chars is over limits imposed by older browsers.

Comment: Please check the URL, why it has 3000 chars? If you want use it to transfer parameters, please try to use [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) or [webstorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), instead of via the url query string.

Comment: Same issue, IE11, iframe URL is 372 characters long... Have you find a solution?

Comment: Just for reference, same error message in my language: *Datová oblast předaná systémové službě je příliš malá.*